# CURL error: SSL certificate error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am getting the above error unless I set the following:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

which is insecure and defeats the purpose of SSL.

I have downloaded the most recent cacert.pem certificate from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.

I have set the following in php.ini and restarted apache.

```
curl.cainfo = /etc/ssl/cacert.pem
```

Which produced the same error. 
So I tried to set at runtime with:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/cacert.pem");
```

and still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that the self signed certificate is signed by a CA in the certficate store you are using?

Answer (score 0):

In case of SSL certificates signed by any Certification Authority (CA), the client app (e.g. browser) verify the SSL certificate with CA. CA tells the client that whether it is a trusted server or not.

When you are using self signed certificates and not using this option

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

you will get error because, your client app will try to verify your self signed SSL certificate with Certification Authority and CA will give error because it's a self signed certificate.

This is the reason we have to use this option to skip the SSL certificate validation step.

Comment: Doesnt this open it up to MITM attacks?

Comment: hi @Kyle, Here is what I found for your question, "Using self-signed certificates does not mean MITM is possible and using a certificate issued by a public CA does not mean MITM is impossible. But, it is more likely that MITM is possible if self-signed certificates are used because the clients dealing with self-signed certificates often deal with these in the wrong way." 

Read this post's answer:

[link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184969/how-mitm-attack-got-performed-on-self-signed-certificate-while-private-keys-is-g)